# Ignore first column from text file and gets value into integer depends on combobox selection c#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: text file]

Hello, I wanna ask how to get every column value from text file into int depends on combobox selection.

I already takes first column into combobox. Here it is code.

[image: combobox]

If 2020-08-15 combobox selected stat1 value will be 20 and stat2 is 88 and rest is.

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            string[] date = line.Split('\t');
            comboBox1.Items.Add(date[0]);
        }
```

How to make it?

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: Read the file again line by line.. compare the first item in the line with the combobox selected value. If it matches... get the other values from the same line and break the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to use a class object to store the parameters. This class will override `ToString` and output what you want to see.

So your class would look something like this:

```
public sealed class MyData
{
    public string Column1 {get;set;}
    public int Column2 {get;set;}
    public int Column3 {get;set;}
    public int Column4 {get;set;}
    public int Column5 {get;set;}
    public override ToString()
    {
        return Column1;
    }
}
```

Then, in your loop:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] items = line.Split('\t');
    var item = new MyData
    {
        Column1 = items[0],
        Column2 = int.Parse(items[1]),
        Column3 = int.Parse(items[2]),
        Column4 = int.Parse(items[3]),
        Column5 = int.Parse(items[4]),
    }
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Now you have all the data bound to the combobox, so if selection changes, you can get at that data by simply casting the item.

```
var myItem = (MyData)comboBox1.Items[0];
```

I haven't tested this, so there may be minor errors.